# HTTP Proxy to Record HTTP/HTTPS traffic

Tags: http-proxy

I am developing a HTTP proxy. The main purpose of developing this is to record HTTP / HTTPS traffic.

**HTTP Case**
This is relatively easy. When I get packet, I accumulate. Once I get complete packet, I send this packet to actual web server.

When actual web server responds I send it to browser.

That way I am able to record HTTP traffic (request, response) properly.

**HTTPS Case**
This one looks bit complex. I have few transport connections to manage it.

First browser sends a CONNECT request to my HTTP proxy, with that I setup  a tunnel to actual web server.

In Tx path, browser sends SSL encrypted data to HTTP proxy, which accumulates it, on getting complete message HTTP proxy sends it to actual web server and also logs the message to a file.

Similarly in Rx path, when actual web server sends SSL encrypted response, HTTP proxy sends the responses to browser and log the response to a file.

To manage above I have below transport connections

Browser (tcp) - HTTP proxy (tcp) connection

HTTP proxy (tcp) - HTTP proxy (tls) connection

HTTP proxy (tls) - Actual Webserver (tls) connection

To some extent I have been successful but not perfect now. I have below issue that blocks me to make it perfect.

I create the certificates dynamically using gnutls certools commands.

Since I create self signed certificates, browsers (say firefox) complains, on adding exception it goes through.

For some links I do not get exception, and corresponding data I do not 
see in browser. For example when I access https://www.dawn.com , looks the images are in https://i.dawn.com server. I never got any exception for i.dawn.com, but firefox never show the images. The firefox debug logs shows contents from i.dawn.com can not be shown because of security issues.

Can somebody help me to learn, how these kind of middle proxies are designed and certificate issues are resolved.

**Certificate generation**

I am following below procedure for certificate generation. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I am using gnutls certtool command to generate certificates

*certtool --generate-privkey --outfile key.pem*

*certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey key.pem --template cert.cfg --outfile cert.pem*

Next I copy /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt to current path.
Next I append cert.pem content to ca-certificates.crt file.

Finally I use key.pem, cert.pem and ca-certificates.crt files for TLS connection.

This procedure I followed from some help page. I am not sure if I am doing it all correct.

Request please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

**Procedure to generate certificates**

We need to behave as CA and for that first we need to generate our certificate, and this certificate should be set explicitly in systems to trust.

*certtool --generate-privkey --outfile ca-key.pem

certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey ca-key.pem --outfile ca-cert.pem*

Now this ca-cert.pem should be set explicitly in system to trust. So that applications sharing system cert store can trust certificates signed by using this CA cert.

I am following https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate to set ca-cert.pem explicitly to trust.

In accepted answer second comment says we need to convert pem file to crt file. On referring whole page my understanding is  that we need to have crt file in PEM format. How do we do that using certtool, any idea....

Next, using *sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates* command, I will set the certificate in system to trus it.

Next, I will generate private key and cert file using commands below

*certtool --generate-privkey --outfile key.pem

certtool --generate-request --load-privkey key.pem --outfile request.pem
certtool --generate-certificate --load-request request.pem --outfile cert.pem --load-ca-certificate ca-cert.pem --load-ca-privkey ca-key.pem*

Then there is one more command as below using template file cert.cfg

*certtool --generate-certificate cert.pem --load-privkey key.pem --template cert.cfg --load-ca-certificate ca-cert.pem --load-ca-privkey ca-key.pem*

Is this command really required? For what purpose it is used.

Please clarify.

Comment: Firefox does not load data from "insecure" servers, presenting an invalid certificate. It does so silently. Does it work if you try to access the image directly, add the exception from there, and reload the page? What I would do is to generate a root certificate that you will explicitly trust. Your proxy would then generate site-specific certificates signed by this root, so you don't have to add exceptions each time. This way, it should work with the images.

Comment: @Pierre, I am bit weak in certificates part. I am editing my question, how I generate certificates, request to let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the steps in http://gnu.ist.utl.pt/software/gnutls/manual/html_node/Invoking-certtool.html . Basically, you create a self-signed certificate that serves as root certificate (points 1-3), that you will explicitly trust in your system certificate store. Then, you use it to sign "child" certificates (points 4+) for each of the proxied websites.

Comment: @Pierre, I will modify my code as per your suggestion. Before that I want to understand it clearly. I went through the link. First two commands to generate dh.pem and rsa.pem I think these are not required, please let me know if it is required. Next step 3, I will do it. It will generate ca-key.pem and ca-cert.pem. How do I make these two are explicitly trusted in my system???? I hope the steps 7 & 8 are not required. Please clarify.

Comment: You are right on the necessary steps (I should have got into details). Trusting the certificate is highly dependent on your system or browser. You are mentioning Firefox, so for this browser you would go to `Preferences > Advanced > Certificates > Authorities` and import from there the root certificate generated in step 3. You need to trust the certificate, not the key.

Comment: I work in Ubuntu 14.04 machines, Just checked link https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate My understanding is if I update system with root certificates, then I do not have import domain specific certificates in browsers like chrome or firefox. Please clarify.

Comment: That is a good source, and what you say is correct for all software using the system store, such as Chrome. Unfortunately, not all browsers do use the system store (Firefox usually uses its own, but I think it is the only exception among the "major" browsers).

Comment: @Pierre Still not clear putting the procedure I am following in my question above, please clarify if I am doing right.

Comment: @Pierre - I have asked the certificate issues in a separate question, if possible please help me earliest. I am really stuck there. The question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101774/create-sign-and-deploy-certificates-in-ubuntu-14-system-using-certtool